# How i can use Video Capture Device with DirectX.Capture C#?

Tags: c#, .net, directx

I am new in C#. I had create an application which record by my webcam. But i want to create a button with the settings of camera(brightness etc). I had download this project

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3566/DirectX-Capture-Class-Library

to help me, but i am confused. If you go to PropertyPages and click Video Capture Device you can change the settings of camera. I can't find it inside the code how i could use only this window. I like to click a button and show me the settings.

Thank you in advance, I am new in C# so don't destroy my reputation, i know that my question is a little bit confused but i am confused :P !

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The workflow of that project related to your question is like this:

1. When you run the application, the `updateMenu` method runs and the items in the menu are created.

   ```
   // Load property pages
       try
       {
           mnuPropertyPages.MenuItems.Clear();
           for (int c = 0; c < capture.PropertyPages.Count; c++)
           {
               p = capture.PropertyPages[c];
               m = new MenuItem(p.Name + "...", new EventHandler(mnuPropertyPages_Click));
               mnuPropertyPages.MenuItems.Add(m);
           }
           mnuPropertyPages.Enabled = (capture.PropertyPages.Count > 0);
       }
       catch { mnuPropertyPages.Enabled = false; }
   ```
2. `PropertyPages` is a property that first time when is called is returning a list of `PropertyPageCollection` and for each item is creating a menu. To see how this collection is created look into the property body. Not all the filters used in the filter graph have PropertyPages.
3. The `PropertyPageCollection`class is receiving the filters and the `graphBuilder`. In the constructor is calling `addFromGraph`. This method creates for each filter a `DirectShowPropertyPage` and adds it to the `InnerList` list inside 
   `PropertyPageCollection`. The code that is creating the `DirectShowPropertyPage` is inside `addIfSupported` method
4. To show the property page this menu event is hooked to all menu items for the filters property pages (see step 1):

   ```
   private void mnuPropertyPages_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
   {
       try
       {
           MenuItem m = sender as MenuItem;
           capture.PropertyPages[m.Index].Show( this );
           updateMenu();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       { 
           MessageBox.Show( "Unable display property page. Please submit a bug report.\n\n" + ex.Message + "\n\n" + ex.ToString() );
       }
   }
   ```
5. This project is collecting all the cameras that you have. To achieve your purpose you can make your own method and pass the video filter (the camera you are using), the name of the filter and the parent of the property page (your main form) and show directly the property page. Add this method in `Capture.cs`, add the reference to `using System.Windows.Forms` in case if is missing.

   ```
   public bool ShowPropertyPage(Control owner )
   {                      
       object filter = null;
       Guid cat = PinCategory.Capture;
   Guid med = MediaType.Interleaved; 
   Guid iid = typeof(IAMStreamConfig).GUID;
   int hr = graphBuilder.FindInterface( 
   ref cat, ref med, videoDeviceFilter, ref iid, out filter );
   if ( hr != 0 )
   {
   med = MediaType.Video ;
   hr = graphBuilder.FindInterface( 
   ref cat, ref med, videoDeviceFilter, ref iid, out filter );
   if ( hr != 0 )
           filter = null;
    }

       ISpecifyPropertyPages specifyPropertyPages = null;
       DsCAUUID cauuid = new DsCAUUID();
       bool hasPropertyPage = false;

       // Determine if the object supports the interface
       // and has at least 1 property page
       try
       {
           specifyPropertyPages = filter  as ISpecifyPropertyPages;
           if (specifyPropertyPages != null)
           {
               int hr = specifyPropertyPages.GetPages(out cauuid);
               if ((hr != 0) || (cauuid.cElems <= 0))
                   specifyPropertyPages = null;
           }
       }
       finally
       {
           if (cauuid.pElems != IntPtr.Zero)
               Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(cauuid.pElems);
       }

       // Add the page to the internal collection
       if (specifyPropertyPages != null)
       {
           DirectShowPropertyPage p = new DirectShowPropertyPage(videDevice.Name, specifyPropertyPages);
           p.Show(owner);
           hasPropertyPage = true;
       }
       return (hasPropertyPage);
   }
   ```
6. Call ShowPropertyPage on some button click event. You can get the video filter using the instance of the Capture class by calling `capture.VideoDevice` and the name `capture.VideoDevice.Name`. Of course first you have to select the camera to work and maybe you need to do some other checks.

   ```
   private void btnShowPropertyPages_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
   {
       try
       {
           if (capture == null)
               throw new ApplicationException("Please select a video and/or audio device.");
           capture.ShowPropertyPage(this);

       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n\n" + ex.ToString());
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your response. I create the method like step 5 and the button like step 6, but it throws me an error : "Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Controler' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ", and i can't understand what is the problem about.

Comment: Is probably missing a reference to the windows forms assembly.

Comment: I can't find which reference is missing. I search it in google and i haven't find anything

Comment: Add a reference to System.Windows.Forms , sorry there is a typo, should be Control

Comment: Ok i correct it but now throws me 2 new errors : Error 1 'WinFormCharpWebCam.mainWinForm.IntPtr(int)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context and Error 2 The name 'txtFilename' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Updated the answer. You don't need that 'txtFilename'. I cannot test it on my pc, I don't have a camera now, but this is the way you can do. If you wanna make it from scratch you can use DirectShow.NET wrapper library over the DirectShow. I think is more organized but this example is more complex and you can simplify it.

Comment: I can understand that you can't test it but you could help me with the errors :D! even if you don't have a camera you could help me build the project without the errors. In button you wrote capture.ShowPropertyPage(etc),  and i correct it without the word capture. Now it gets in ShowPropertyPage but it don't get inside the "if (specifyPropertyPages != null)" . I don't know why!

Comment: Does your camera has property page? Also check if the video filter that is passed, is for your camera. It will not work if the device (camera) is not selected previously.

Comment: Yes it's Microsoft VX-6000 and when i run the CaptureTest project like i wrote in my question it worked fine and shows me the property pages.

Comment: I know why, cannot cast from Filter to ISpecifyPropertyPages. I updated the answer.

Comment: I update my code too but it throws me an error: " Error 1 Cannot convert type 'IBaseFilter' to 'DShowNET.ISpecifyPropertyPages' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion " is in this line of your code "specifyPropertyPages = videFilter as ISpecifyPropertyPages;"

Comment: This should do it, Forgot that you can show the property page for the capture pin or another. I cannot debug to see. Tell me if this fix it. Check this method 'addFromGraph' maybe you need to change the PinCategory or MediaType

Comment: Sorry my english isn't so good so i don't understand you,what do you suggest me to fix? i confused...

Comment: I updated the code. You have to get the pin interface filter from the video Filter(Video device filter) and for that  filter you can show the property page. Look at the new code. Some cameras don't have Capture pin, only Preview pin. I said to change the PinCategory or MediaType according to your camera, In case you don't know just try it like in 'addFromGraph'. For reference look into the 'addFromGraph' method. (i forgot in which class is it, don;t have the code now, use find)

Comment: Unfortenetely it's not working. I am trying to load the form DXPropPages(example on DirectShowLib) but when i run it alone it's ok,when a load this form to my button click...it's a disaster! It throws me almost 50 errors... I let it for now and i am searching for another way. If you could help me it will be perfect!